# How to calculate mean only for fields which apply condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table:

```
    name     start    end     description   mark
0    ag       20       30       None        0.3
1    bgb      21       111      'a'         0.5
2    cdd      31       101      None        0.2
3    ag       17       19       'Bla'       0.55
4    ag       20       22       None        0.9
```

I want to calculate the mean diff (`end`-`start`) for every group (`name`) only if `mark` > sigma

for example, for `sigma = 0.5`

```
   name     diff
0    ag       mean((19-17)+(22-20))      
1    bgb      111-21 (=90)      
2    cdd      0
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Have you tried anything before posting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
sigma=0.5
(df.end.sub(df.start)
   .mul(df.mark>=sigma)        # > or >=, your choice
   .groupby(df['name']).mean()
   .reset_index(name='diff')
 )
```

Output:

```
  name       diff
0   ag   1.333333
1  bgb  90.000000
2  cdd   0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Create new column by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) first and the aggregate `mean`:

```
sigma = 0.5
df1 = (df.assign(diff = df.end.sub(df.start).where(df.mark >= sigma, 0))
         .groupby('name', as_index=False)['diff']
         .mean())

print (df1)
  name       diff
0   ag   1.333333
1  bgb  90.000000
2  cdd   0.000000
```